# If statement test with an attribute from another file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on an XSL template that has an if statement in it. Here is the xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="config"
    select="document('config.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:if test="config/value/@toggle = true">
        <xsl:text>IT WORKED</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

What I need to do is test the if statement with attributes from an XML that I have loaded into a  variable.

Here is the other(config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    <value toggle="true" />

</config>
```

Obviously this isnt working for me, so I was wondering if anyone could point out the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to reference a variable, you need to use the `$` prefix, so it should be `$config` not `config`.

Secondly, the `$config` then references the document node, not the root element (which also happens to be named `config`).

Taking both of this into account, your `xsl:if` statement should be as follows:

```
<xsl:if test="$config/config/value/@toggle = 'true'">
```

Comment: To clarify things, if the name of the other document was xConfig, would it be as follows:
<xsl:if test="$xConfig/config/value/@toggle = true">

Comment: No, the variable name can be the same.. Just that in the variable declaration the document's name changes from `config.xml` to `xConfig.xml`

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, the quotes were why your initial reply didnt work. But I'm good to go now. Thanks!